# Sending complex object into Fragment android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have to send complex object into a fragment.
I used this code but it does not work.

```
companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: CustomerWithAccounts, param2: String) = TransactionsListFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putParcelable(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                println("$param1 $param2")
            }
        }

        private const val dialogTag = "transaction_list_dialog"
        fun display(fragmentManager: FragmentManager): TransactionsListFragment {
            val transactionListDialog = TransactionsListFragment()
            transactionListDialog.show(fragmentManager, dialogTag)
            return transactionListDialog
        }
    }
```

and I send it like this.

```
   private val onItemClickListener = object : TransactionAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
        override fun onItemClick(view: View?, obj: CustomerWithAccounts?, position: Int) {
            if (obj != null) {
                val fragmentManager: FragmentManager = childFragmentManager
                val fragment = TransactionsListFragment
                fragment.newInstance(obj, "DIAA")
                fragment.display(fragmentManager)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my Modal class

```
class CustomerWithAccounts(
        @Embedded val customerAccounts: CustomerAccounts,
        @Relation(parentColumn = "customerOwnerId", entityColumn = "customerId")
        val customer: Customer
)
```

How to do that please help.

Answer (score 1):

Writing code that can be generated from XML is questionable.

Use navigation with safe-args plugin, which is rather the framework way of passing `Object`.
It's a code-generator plugin which utilizes the arguments defined in the navigation graph XML.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.3"
    }
}
```

Per module:

```
// apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
```

The outcome are generated bindings alike: `TransactionFragmentArgs implements NavArgs`.
See: [Pass data between destinations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data) for how to declare these argument-definitions ...

Answer (score 0):

You messed up in creating Object . you are basically creating two objects right now . Fix it .

```
private val onItemClickListener = object : TransactionAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    override fun onItemClick(view: View?, obj: CustomerWithAccounts?, position: Int) {
        if (obj != null) {
            val fragment = TransactionsListFragment.newInstance(obj, "DIAA")
            fragment.display(childFragmentManager)
        }
    }
}
```

Well you need to fix your display method too . Why r u creating another Object in Display ?

```
fun display(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) {
    show(fragmentManager, dialogTag)
}
```

Comment: You were creating 3 objects at one time . use the code above it should work now .